# Mongodb aggregate query $match and $group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Here are some sample entries from my mongodb collection:

```
{ name: "Tom", timestamp: "Jun 4" },
{ name: "Jerry", timestamp: "Jun 4" },
{ name: "Tom", timestamp: "Jun 2" },
{ name: "Tom", timestamp: "May 25" },
{ name: "Jerry", timestamp: "May 21" },
{ name: "Robin", timestamp: "May 19" }
```

Every time a user logs into my app, I create an entry for the user.

> **Question:** I need to find out the list of users who have not logged into my app for the last 5 days. That is, no entry after *May 30*. Today is **June 4**.
>
> **Answer:** *Robin*

Attempt 1:

```
[ 
   { "$match": { "timestamp": { "$lt": FIVE_DAYS_AGO } } }, 
   { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } },
   { "$group": { "_name": "$name", "lastSynced": { "$last": "$timestamp" } }
]
```

*Gives incorrect result* because there can be entries between NOW and FIVE_DAYS_AGO which is not considered.

Attempt 2:

```
[
   { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } },
   { "$group": { "_name": "$name", "lastSynced": { "$last": "$timestamp" } }
]
```

*Not Optimized*! because it returns all the distinct user entries. I then have to loop through the result and filter out entries where the timestamp is FIVE_DAYS_AGO.

How do I construct the query to get list of users who do not have entry in last X days?

Comment: Do you really have data like this :: timestamp: "Jun 4" means is it a string look like that or does `timestamp` is of datatype `date` ?

Comment: As your `timestamp` is in string format, you need to use [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator, if you look into the docs, there are only limited date stings, which can be converted. So, I suggest you to update the field to proper convertible value.

Comment: @whoami , you got it right. It is `timestamp` of datatype `date`. For clarity to explanation, I wrote it as a string. But I suppose I confused others while doing that. My bad.

Comment: Hey @ngShravil.py, thanks your solution helped.

Answer (score 0):

Few points to note:

1. Please consider my comment.

   > As your `timestamp` is in string format, you need to use `$dateFromString` operator, if you look into the docs, there are only limited date stings, which can be converted. So, I suggest you to update the field to proper convertible value.
2. Your `$group` is incorrect. It expects `_id` field otherwise it will throw the below error:

```
The field '_name' must be an accumulator object.
```

3. I think, year value is required in `timestamp`, I was getting this error:

```
(ConversionFailure) Error parsing date string
```

With the above points considered, if your collection looks like below:

```
[
  {
    name: "Tom",
    timestamp: "06 04 2020"
  },
  {
    name: "Jerry",
    timestamp: "06 04 2020"
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
    timestamp: "06 02 2020"
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
    timestamp: "05 25 2020"
  },
  {
    name: "Jerry",
    timestamp: "05 21 2020"
  },
  {
    name: "Robin",
    timestamp: "05 19 2020"
  }
]
```

Then below PyMongo query will be helpful:

```py
from datetime import datetime

five_days_ago = datetime(2020, 5, 30)

db.test12.aggregate([
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$name',
      'timestap_list': {
        '$push': {
          '$dateFromString': {
            'dateString': '$timestamp',
            'format': '%m %d %Y'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      'timestamp': {
        '$allElementsTrue': {
          '$map': {
            'input': '$timestap_list',
            'as': 't',
            'in': {
              '$lte': [
                '$$t',
                five_days_ago
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$match': {
      'timestamp': True
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      'timestamp': 0
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
{
  '_id': 'Robin'
}
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lh_A4nWjlA2)

Comment: Hey @ngShravil.py, as I mentioned above, the timestamp field is of datatype `date` actually, for the sake of explanation, I showed it as a string. My bad. Your solution worked. I, however, have another question. what if there was a third field. `status`. and I need to select only the rows where `status: true`. I have achieved it by adding another `$match` before `$group`. It works. But is that the right way?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. If this helped then you can upvote and accept this as answer. Thanks.